# How can I get rid of the Raw Type problem in my Binary Tree Class

Tags: generics, binary-tree, raw-types

I really need help here. I just do not know how get rid of the Raw Type Message. Here is my code:

```
public class BinaryTree<T> {

    TreeElement root;

    public BinaryTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    public BinaryTree(T data, BinaryTree<T> bl, BinaryTree<T> br) {
        root = new TreeElement(data);
        if (bl != null) {
            root.left = bl.root;
        }
        if (br != null) {
            root.right = br.root;
        }
    }

    class TreeElement {
        T data;
        TreeElement left;
        TreeElement right;

        public TreeElement(T data) {
            this.data = data;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The Raw Type message appears here: `public BinaryTree (T data, BinaryTree<T> bl, BinaryTree<T> br)`

Multiple markers at this line
- BinaryTree is a raw type. References to generic type BinaryTree should be parameterized
- BinaryTree is a raw type. References to generic type BinaryTree should be parameterized

Just typing `public BinaryTree (T data, BinaryTree bl, BinaryTree br)` creates the same problem.

It would be awesome if anybody could tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Yes, i changed the language here to english xD Binaerbaum always means Binarytree here

Comment: I copy-pasted your code into my IDE and I do not get any errors. Consider creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or provide more details.

Comment: Allright thanks :)